# Inserting an array into an array

Tags: arrays, c

For making a tictactoe game, I decided that the optimal solution will be to create an array of arrays. I have found solutions only for C# and C++, and I am not sure if this option exists in C. I wonder if I can use some libraries available for C to create an array of arrays.

The code I'm trying to execute:

```
char first_row[] = {' ', ' ', ' '};
char second_row[] = {' ', ' ', ' '};
char third_row[] = {' ', ' ', ' '};
char rows[] = {first_row, second_row, third_row};
```

I'd also like to know how to access an array inside an array. A pythonist myself, I find the absence of this feature completely blowing my mind.

upd: I have found information that it's possible in C99, however, no description of how to make it.

Comment: Try `char *rows[] = { ... };` instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, perfect! This works. How to access the array inside an array? Like `rows[0][0]`?

Comment: An alternative way: `char rows[][3] = {{' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' '}};` and access it like `rows[2][1]` In general that's how multiple-dimensional arrays (aka arrays of arrays of arrays of ...) are made in C, e.g. `int mat_3d[5][3][42];`

Comment: Thanks everyone! Could you post it as answers, please?

Comment: Just as a side note: As you mention C++, hopefully you are not using `std::vector` of `std::vector`s – while working, it would create a jagged array (the equivalent to the array of pointers in the accepted solution) – better suited, as dimensions are fix anyway, would be a `std::array<std::array<char, 3>, 3>`, corresponding to the 2D array below (and actually that one could be used as well…).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a two-dimensional 3x3 array in C, use the following,

```
char rows[3][3] = {{' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' '}};
```

You can omit the first dimension in which case the dimension will be derived from the number of initializers. Like:

```
char rows[][3] = {{' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' '}};
```

Note that the second dimension `3` is mandatory here and cannot be omitted.

You can also do the following, but then your array is not a two dimensional array, it is an array of pointers instead.

```
char *rows[] = {first_row, second_row, third_row};
```

In both cases, you access your element with the same syntax like `rows[0][0]`.